# bash curl with session cookies?

Tags: bash, curl, cookies, session-cookies

I managed to get the curl output of a web-page that using site minder authentication by manually extracting the cookie from firefox and using it in the curl command:

```
curl "example.com/firstexample" -H "Host: example.com" -H "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:50.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/50.0" -H "Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8" -H "Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5" --compressed -H "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" -H "X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest" -H "Referer: http://example.com" -H --cookie-jar cookies.txt --cookie cookies.txt -H "Connection: keep-alive"
```

However, the curl works only as long as the session lasts. Once a new session starts i.e. the cookie session id and other stuff changes - the curl no longer works obviously.

Is there a way to get the subsequent cookies/session ids via curl to continue seemlessly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out the `--cookie` and `--cookie-jar` options on `curl` in the man page.  They should do what you need.